# Pod Security Policy not working as intended

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am creating a Pod Security Policy to stop ALL users from creating a Pod as Root user. My cluster is on GKE.
The steps Ive carried out till now are

1) Enable PodSecurityPolicy in my cluster

```
gcloud beta container clusters update standard-cluster-11  --enable-pod-security-policy
```

2) Define the Policy. The policy is simple and restricts root user.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  name: a-restrict-root
spec:
  privileged: false
  runAsUser:
    rule: MustRunAsNonRoot  # <------ Root user restricted.
  seLinux:
    rule: RunAsAny
  fsGroup:
    rule: RunAsAny
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: RunAsAny
  volumes:
  - '*'
```

3) And then ofcourse implementing the correct RBAC rules so that it can be implemented for ALL users.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: gce:podsecuritypolicy:a-restrict-root
  labels:
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - policy
  resourceNames:
  - a-restrict-root
  resources:
  - podsecuritypolicies
  verbs:
  - use
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: gce:podsecuritypolicy:a-restrict-root
  labels:
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: gce:podsecuritypolicy:a-restrict-root
subjects:
- kind: Group
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  name: system:serviceaccounts
```

Now comes the part where I try to spin up a Pod. The pod definition looks like this :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
    fsGroup: 0
  volumes:
  - name: sec-ctx-vol
    emptyDir: {}
  containers:
  - name: sec-ctx-demo
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    volumeMounts:
    - name: sec-ctx-vol
      mountPath: /data/demo
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

As you can see, the `runAsUser` is set to `0` meaning `root`.

When I run `kubectl create -f pod.yaml`, the pod is creating and goes into `Running` state.

When I exec into the Pod, I can see all process running as root

```
$ kubectl exec -it security-context-demo -- sh
# ps aux
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.0  0.0   4336   812 ?        Ss   19:25   0:00 /bin/sh -c node server.js
root           6  0.4  0.5 772124 22656 ?        Sl   19:25   0:00 node server.js
root          11  0.0  0.0   4336   724 ?        Ss   19:26   0:00 sh
root          16  0.0  0.0  17500  2072 ?        R+   19:26   0:00 ps aux
```

But based on my PodSecurityPolicy this should NOT be allowed. Is there something I have missed ?

**UPDATE :**

I spun up a default nginx pod that I know always starts as root user. Its manifest is :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
```

And when I create it, it too starts up successfully.

```
$ kubectl get po
NAME                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx                   1/1       Running   0          2m
```

Whereas because of the PSP, it should not start up.

Answer (score 2):

If you fetch the created pod from the API, it will contain an annotation indicating which PSP allowed the pod. I expect a different PSP is in place which allows the pod

Comment: Thanks for the indication. You indeed give me a clue. It returns `kubernetes.io/psp: gce.privileged`. Since this is a GKE cluster, there are a bunch load of other psps like `gce.privileged`, `gce.persistent-volume-binder`,`gce.unprivileged-addon` etc etc. When I try to delete them, they get recreated automatically. Any idea how i can disable them permanently ?

Comment: The privileged policies are granted to specific serviceaccounts in the kube-system namespace. Running your pod in a different namespace or with a dedicated service account would avoid inheriting the gce.privileged permissions

Answer (score 0):

I got what you are missing just add this in your pod config file:

Before that, make sure to `create the user (say, appuser) uid -> say, 999` and `group (say, appgroup) gid ->say, 999` in the Docker container, and then try starting the container with that user and add:

```
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 999
```

This might be a good read: [SecurityContext](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod)

Also, when you are doing this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
    fsGroup: 0
```

**You are overriding the PodSecurityPolicy** see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-container)

**Update: 1**

> How to fix this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  name: a-restrict-root
spec:
  privileged: false
  defautlAllowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  # This is redundant with non-root + disallow privilege escalation,
  # but we can provide it for defense in depth.
  requiredDropCapabilities:
    - ALL
  hostIPC: false
  hostPID: false
  runAsUser:
    # Require the container to run without root privileges.
    rule: 'MustRunAsNonRoot'
  seLinux:
    # This policy assumes the nodes are using AppArmor rather than SELinux.
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: 'MustRunAs'
    ranges:
      # Forbid adding the root group.
      - min: 1
        max: 65535
  fsGroup:
    rule: 'MustRunAs'
    ranges:
      # Forbid adding the root group.
      - min: 1
        max: 65535
```

Comment: This will allow the Pod to run as Non root which is fine. What Im trying to do is to stop root from running in my cluster. Your solution wont help me do that. The Pod that I want to stop should have `runAsUser: 0`. Something is missing on my psp side.

Comment: `runAsUser` , It's applicable to all the containers, so you only need to add it to the pod spec if you want to have it in all the containers of that particular pod. As per the docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod



That way you could enforce that there is no process starting with root to harden the container.

Comment: You need to take a look at this open issue - https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/213. I know, setting the guid smells like a workaround but there is no other way as of now.

Comment: When you put `runAsUser:0` and `fsGroup:0` to  Security settings that you specify for a Container you are overriding the pod security context. Please, see the updated answer.

Comment: The `SecurityContext` that I have provided is for the Pod and not for the container. I am not overriding any context for the container. My aim is not to start the Pod as NonRoot or as user `999`. My aim is to start a pod as root and have the PodSecurityPolicy step in and stop the pod from running because the pod is starting up as root.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not making it clear but what I mean to say is when you put the user mod in  `your pod definition` kubernetes sees it as an allowed behavior as overriding is allowed. It won't stop.

Comment: Could you just remove the `SecurityContext` from pod definition should you see the error while starting `privileged container`. Else, kubernetes set `defaultAllowPrivilegeEscalation` to true. If you want to set it to false see the updated answer.

Comment: `privileged` and `MustRunAsNonRoot` are 2 different things. Im not focusing on privileged for now. Just on `MustRunAsNonRoot`. Please see my update. I started a default nginx pod with no overriding. With my PSP, it should not come up. But it still did come up.